# Update AddThis description/summary after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, sharing, addthis

I'm wondering if its possible to update on the fly the description/summary that shows up when you try to share to Facebook via AddThis? To explain a little more I allow the user update the language on the page using jQuery and JSON (don't have any backend capability on this site/server so no PHP I'm afraid).

So when a user in Japan for example views the site and changes the language to Japanese and tried to share the page with presumably other Japanese speaking friends unfortunately the summary and title are still in the English.

I seem to be able to update the title but I cannot seem to update the description provided.

I have tried putting in Open Graph meta tags in with a default description then updating the content of that when the language is changed but AddThis/Facebook doesn't take notice of the change so I guess I need to directly pass the new description to Facebook or AddThis but I can't seem to figure it out.

p.s please see image for the description I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: When the user changes the language to a different language, have you considered just loading a new 'page-japanese.html'? And then allow the user to share that content? For example, on my site, the user can get content in Arabic or English.  You can check out the source: http://zacharyhuberty.com/index.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well unfortunately a lot of work has gone into the jQuery text language check and its not really feasible int he time frame I have to create new pages for all the different languages we need to cover.

Comment: _“Well unfortunately a lot of work has gone into the jQuery text language check”_ – that was time (not) well wasted then. The language should be part of the URL in any case – only that way machines like search engine robots or the Facebook scraper tool can access the different languages properly.